# Translate parts of a string individually using Twig and the i18n extension?

Tags: internationalization, twig, gettext, twig-extension, php-gettext

I have a string that looks like

```
This is a list of all items with number 123456 in United States.
```

and I want to translate it to Swedish as

```
Detta är en lista över alla artiklar med nummer 123456 i USA.
```

The problem is that the number `123456` and the country name `United States` are generated dynamically, but the string is delivered in its final form to the Twig template (it's used for `<meta name="description" ... />`.

I already have a `.po` file with country names that I'm translating, including

```
English             Swedish
United States       USA
```

The generated meta description string can have any combination of numbers and country names, so I can't hardcode any translations for the entire string. Is there any way I can re-use my existing translations for the country names and have them translated inside the meta description string, and have the number just stay as it is? Or do I need to somehow split the string up first, and then translate each part individually?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a PHP programmer, so I use pseude code:

```
num_items = 42;
country = "United States";
string = sprintf(gettext("... items with number %d in %s"),
                 num_items, gettext(country));
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: This is sort of what I ended up doing. I am using `gettext()` directly instead of the Twig translation extension to generate the translated string in my controller, and then I pass it to the view. What I had in mind in the question, though, was if there was a way to get the translation extension to lookup the correct translation for a string that follows a certain pattern, and translate it but copy "variables" (the number in the above example) from the source string to the translated one... guess not though.

Comment: I don't really understand your plan.  But there are two ways of interpolating variables.  Either the "items with number {{ number }} in {{ country }}" form, or the nested gettext invocation from my answer.  So your guess is probably right.